# How to remove ORG names and GPE from noun chunk in spacy

Tags: python-3.x, string, replace, nlp, spacy

I have the following code

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Span
import en_core_web_lg
nlpsm = en_core_web_lg.load()

doc = nlpsm(text)

finalwor = []
    fil = [i for i in doc.ents if i.label_.lower() in ["person"]]
    fil_a = [i for i in doc.ents if i.label_.lower() in ['GPE']]
    fil_b = [i for i in doc.ents if i.label_.lower() in ['ORG']]
    for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:
        if chunk not in fil and chunk not in fil_a and chunk not in fil_b:
            finalwor=list(doc.noun_chunks)
            print("finalwor after noun_chunk", finalwor)
        else: 
            chunk in fil_a and chunk in fil_b
            entword=list(str(chunk.text).replace(str(chunk.text),""))
            finalwor.extend(entword)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. If the text is 'IT manager at Google'

My current output is "IT manager, Google'

Ideal output that I want is "IT manager".

Basically I want the company names and GPE names to replaced by empty string or just plainly just delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here, `finalwor=list(doc.noun_chunks)`, you are appending all the nouns that appear in your `doc` to the final word instead of just the noun that justifies your statement

You might be looking for something like this:

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Span
import en_core_web_lg
nlpsm = en_core_web_lg.load()

doc = nlpsm('Maria, IT manager at Google and gardener')

finalwor = []
fil = [i for i in doc.ents if i.label_.lower() in ["person"]]
fil_a = [i for i in doc.ents if i.label_.lower() in ['gpe']]
fil_b = [i for i in doc.ents if i.label_.lower() in ['org']]

for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:
    if chunk not in fil and chunk not in fil_a and chunk not in fil_b:
        finalwor.append(chunk)

print("finalwor after noun_chunk", finalwor)
```

finalwor after noun_chunk [IT manager, gardener]